# User name in Url asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008

Im about to start my new project, and got architecture problem. I want each user to have their own link to their personal profile.

Like this: Localhost/user/MyRandomUserName

so when i am accutally gonna click on link, i gonna have to find MyRandomUser in db, and replace string with actual Guid of user.

Website wil have possibility to log on with facebook and gmail accounts (to make it easier to access webpage), so there will be possibility of duplicates of same names.

Problem is, how smart is it to put user name as an "id" in url?

I can see youtube something similar, but how does it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Website will have possibility to log on with facebook and gmail accounts
```

You will have id for gmail, facebook for login which should be unique and you will ask user to give a unique name for your site which be served as url and if he does not then  or you can show GUID instead of name.

Comment: Website will have possibility to log on with facebook and gmail accounts, You will have unique id for gmail, facebook to uniquery identify user and you will ask user to give a unique name for your site and if he does not you will show GUID instead of name

Comment: but what am i gonna do if i actually gonna hit 2 of the same usernames from gmail and facebook?

Comment: You need to rely on unique user names within your site primarily if a facebook comes in your site and this user name does not exists in your site you can use this facebook username as a unique username in your site. and if you have conflicting user name within your site then tell the user to get a unique name for your site.

Answer (score 1):

You can use asp.net routing. Read this article for more details:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201(v=vs.100).aspx

You can extend user profile with unique id that is not userId and then use it.